# Is there any theorem similar to the Tutte–Berge formula?

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Tutte–Berge formula is a characterization of the **size** of a **maximum matching** in a graph.

> The theorem states that the size of a maximum matching of a graph
> ${\displaystyle G=(V,E)}$ equals $${\displaystyle {\frac {1}{2}}\min _{U\subseteq V}\left(|V|-(\operatorname {odd} (G-U)-|U|)\right),}$$ where
> ${\displaystyle \operatorname {odd} (H)}$ counts **how many of the connected components** of the graph ${\displaystyle H}$ have an **odd number** of vertices.

And we can see from the formula that it's independent of even connected components of $G-U$.

I wonder if there are any other graph parameters related to even connected components of $G-U$ or connected components of $G-U$. Indeed, it doesn’t have to be in the form of  $G-U$.